# Calling Python from C that's extending Python

Tags: python, c

So, I'm working on a C library that extends Python, per [this page](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/extending.html).  It's working great, but I want more.

I'm serving up JSON in a string to the Python app, where I'm running json.loads on it.  Basically, in the main Python app I'm running

```
result = json.loads(my_module.get_json_string())
```

Because I'm only ever going to care about getting the data in Python in a nice Pythonic dictionary form, I'd rather put the json.loads part into my C program.  I'd like to do this:

```
result = my_module.get_result()
```

And, I'd like to do it using the nice, dependable json module that's already there.  How do I do that?  I can see how I could do it from C if I were running the interpreter from C, but that's not what I'm doing.  I want C pseudocode that goes something like this:

```
- Obtain the json string like I am now
- Call Python to convert it to a Python object using json.loads
- return the Python object
```

Any pointers (other than to the local mental hospital?)